# Is India's latest election indicative of an end to the caste based political system?

Tags: election, parties, india

Uttar Pradesh always well known for caste based politics and mainly there were 2 parties , BSP for *dalits* and SP for *Yadavas*. But In this election, all caste based political parties are defeated and BJP won with a great margin.

So can we take this as a good sign that **Caste based politics is going for an end in India** or in other words **is India getting freedom from caste based politics?**

Comment: I'm sorry, but we generally do not answer speculative questions. We can not tell the future. And those of us who think they can, have no way to prove that their predictions are correct until they become true (and then you don't need their answers anymore).